# postgres container doesn't take password from environment variable

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, docker-stack

I'm using a postgres container as part of my microservice application. This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:alpine
COPY *.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I can build this image and publish it to my azure image registry. Also I can use this image within my docker stack yml File:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    webserver:
        image: myreg.azurecr.io/webserver:latest
        volumes:
            - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
            - /var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443

    postgres:
        image: myreg.azurecr.io/postgresql:latest
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my-super-secure-password
        volumes:
            - /data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
            - /data/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

....
```

But when I try to connect to this container, I get the following log (from this container)

```
2018-04-03 10:37:40.836 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2018-04-03 10:37:40.836 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2018-04-03 10:37:40.850 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/
2018-04-03 10:37:40.936 UTC [17] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-04-03 1
2018-04-03 10:37:40.956 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-04-03 10:37:48.924 UTC [24] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2018-04-03 10:37:48.924 UTC [24] DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

But when I go into this container with `docker exec` I can see my password:

```
$ docker exec -it 7224df929a21 bash
# printenv
PG_SHA256=3ccb4e25fe7a7ea6308dea103cac202963e6b746697366d72ec2900449a5e713
HOSTNAME=7224df929a21
TERM=xterm
PG_MAJOR=10
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my-super-secure-password
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
LANG=en_US.utf8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PG_VERSION=10.1
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
_=/bin/printenv
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is in /data/postgresql? I would think you'll only need to mount to /var/lib/postgres/data. and you are copying .sh files to your entrypoint (no .sql which I would expect, but okay .sh is possible)?

Comment: I removed the first volume mount - without any result.

Comment: If your Postgres data volume was initialized with a different password, you'll need to remove both the volume and the container and start up from scratch. The initial container startup script sets the superuser password, so you'll have to initialize both container and volume again.

Comment: @Mark thank you for this, this just saved me. I tried to have separate `dev` and `prod` secrets and it wasn't connecting on prod and it's because I had it initialized with dev on the same volume.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when running a postgres instance in Kubernetes. It was solved by removing the old persistent volumes + claims and deploying everything from scratch.